# Filtering concrete data with SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have this simple sqlite database:

```
_id  ----- name -----  age  -----  phone

01        John         34           111
02        Mary         44           222
03        Anna         53           333
```

To show all the contacts in my list, I am using the cursor as follows:

```
public Cursor loadCursorContacts (){

    String[] columns = new String[] {CN_ID, CN_NAME, CN_PHONE, CN_AGE};

    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, columnas, null, null, null, null, CN_AGE+" ASC");

}
```

My intention is to show only contacts with age over 40 years.
I'm looking for and I can find the way to do it with rawQuery (although I have not managed to apply it to a cursor), but I can not find the way to do it with the sqlite syntax db.query, as I have in my code.

What would be the correct way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the 3d and 4th argument of the [`query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String)) method like this:

```
db.query(
    TABLE_NAME, 
    columnas, 
    "age > ?", 
    new String[] {String.valueOf(40)}, 
    null, null, CN_AGE+" ASC"
);
```

The 3d argument is the `WHERE` part of the SQL statement (without the keyword `WHERE`) and may include the placeholders `?` which will be replaced by the items of the array in the 4th argument.
 
So the placeholder `?` in the 3d argument will be replaced by `"40"` and the statement will eventually be:

```
SELECT <columnas> FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE age > 30
```